# Install packages in virtualenv without pip

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, quantlib

I use virtualenv for all of my projects in the usual way: create a project folder, create a virtualenv, install the required packages via pip.

However I am now trying to install pyql (https://github.com/enthought/pyql) into a virtualenv but it is not available through pip. I have followed the getting started instructions (https://github.com/enthought/pyql/blob/master/docs/source/getting_started.rst) by installing the standard QuantLib c++ library onto my system and am now up to the point where I now need to install pyql.

I have downloaded pyql from git but the problem is that I dont want to just run `make build` and `make test` because that will install pyql onto my system python. I want to install it into a virtualenv. How do I do that? I've only ever installed packages into virtualenv's using pip.

UPDATE:

I have activated the virtualenv and then run `make build` which gives the following:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
/usr/local/lib/python3.3/distutils/extension.py:132: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'cython_directives'
  warnings.warn(msg)
missing cimport in module 'quantlib.methods.finitedifferences.solvers': ./quantlib/pricingengines/vanilla/_vanilla.pxd
missing cimport in module 'quantlib.methods.finitedifferences.solvers': ./quantlib/methods/finitedifferences/solvers/fdmbackwardsolver.pxd
missing cimport in module 'quantlib.pricingengines': quantlib/instruments/credit_default_swap.pyx
missing cimport in module 'quantlib.time': quantlib/instruments/credit_default_swap.pyx
missing cimport in module 'quantlib.instruments': quantlib/instruments/implied_volatility.pyx
missing cimport in module 'quantlib.pricingengines': quantlib/instruments/option.pyx
missing cimport in module 'quantlib.methods.finitedifferences.solvers': quantlib/methods/finitedifferences/solvers/fdmbackwardsolver.pyx
missing cimport in module 'quantlib.methods.finitedifferences.solvers': quantlib/methods/finitedifferences/solvers/fdmbackwardsolver.pxd
running build_ext
skipping 'quantlib/math/array.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'quantlib/math/hestonhwcorrelationconstraint.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'quantlib/sim/simulate.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'quantlib/pricingengines/vanilla/mcvanillaengine.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'quantlib/termstructures/yields/piecewise_yield_curve.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'quantlib/termstructures/credit/piecewise_default_curve.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'quantlib/settings.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'quantlib/test/test_cython_bug.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'quantlib/time/businessdayconvention.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
```

As mentioned, I have the quantlib c++ library installed as required. Then within the virtualenv I have installed cython.

That 2nd line of the error mentions /usr/local/lib/python3.3. Shouldn't it be using the python from within the virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Makefile https://github.com/enthought/pyql/blob/master/Makefile invokes python during build so you may be allright as long as your virtualenv is activated when you `make build`

Comment: Thanks. I don't seem to be having much luck. I'll post an update to my original question to show what is happening.